# Order of Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, android-app, sorting

I wondered whether there is a order in the list of Stack Exchange sites in the Android application, as Stack Overflow and Super User, the biggest sites (I think so) are on number 1 and 3. So if there even is an order, by what variable is it sorted?